# How can I get my java chat client and server to exchange messages from a textfield

Tags: java, io, network-programming, chat

I'm writing a chat program in Java using a GUI that looks like this[image: GUI]

The idea is to start the server on one computer and the client on another (or multiple) (I'm currently just running both on the same computer).  After a server is started, a client enters the host number and port number and hits connect.  All of this is working so far.  Once connected, either the user or the server can type in the textField and hit Send, and the message can be sent to the server, and the server sends the message to all clients.

my question is: **How can I send text from the clients to the server and vice-versa?**

 I'm having trouble grasping how this would work.  The server sits in a while loop and waits for more connections (all which work), so I don't know how it can accept text and then push it back.

Here's the entire program so you can compile it and see the problems I'm having:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Chat extends Frame implements Runnable, WindowListener, ActionListener, ItemListener
{   

    int port = 44004;
    String host =  "127.0.0.1";
    //GUI objects
    TextField ipAddressField = new TextField();
    TextField portField = new TextField(""+port); 
    TextField hostField = new TextField(host);
    TextField inputBox = new TextField();
    static TextArea conversationBox = new TextArea();
    Button startServerButton = new Button("Start Server");
    Button sendButton = new Button("Send");
    Button changeHost = new Button("Change Host");
    Button changePort = new Button("Change Port");
    Button connectButton = new Button("Connect");
    Button disconnectButton = new Button("Disconnect");
    Label hostLabel = new Label("Host:");
    Label portLabel = new Label("Port:");
    MenuBar mb = new MenuBar();
    Menu colorMenu = new Menu("Color");
    CheckboxMenuItem redItem = new CheckboxMenuItem("Red");
    CheckboxMenuItem blueItem = new CheckboxMenuItem("Blue");
    CheckboxMenuItem orangeItem = new CheckboxMenuItem("Orange");
    CheckboxMenuItem blackItem = new CheckboxMenuItem("Black");

    //runtime variables
    Color color = Color.red;
    volatile boolean kill = false;
    volatile boolean isServer = false;
    volatile boolean isClient = false;
    String connections[];

    //messaging variables
    String message;
    Scanner in;
    PrintWriter out;

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        new Chat();
    }

    ServerSocket server;
    Socket s;
    //gui components

    protected Chat()
    {
        double[] colWeight = {1,1,1,1,1,1};
        double[] rowWeight = {5,1,1,1,1};
        int[] colWidth = {1,1,1,1,1,1};
        int[] rowHeight = {5,1,1,1,1};
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl.rowHeights = rowHeight;
        gbl.columnWidths = colWidth;
        gbl.columnWeights = colWeight;
        gbl.rowWeights = rowWeight;

        setBounds(100,100,400,600);
        setLayout(gbl);

        //add conversation box
        this.conversationBox.setSize(400, 400);
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 5;
        c.gridheight = 5;
        c.fill = 1;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        gbl.setConstraints(this.conversationBox, c);

        //input text box
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 4;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.fill = 1;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 5;
        gbl.setConstraints(this.inputBox, c);

        //send button
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.fill = 1;
        c.gridx = 4;
        c.gridy = 5;
        gbl.setConstraints(this.sendButton, c);

        //host label
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.fill = 1;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 6;
        gbl.setConstraints(this.hostLabel, c);

        //host input
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.fill = 1;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 6;
        gbl.setConstraints(this.hostField, c);

        //change host button
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.fill = 1;
        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 6;
        gbl.setConstraints(this.changeHost, c);

        //start server button
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.fill = 1;
        c.gridx = 4;
        c.gridy = 6;
        gbl.setConstraints(this.startServerButton, c);

        //row
        //port label
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.fill = 1;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 7;
        gbl.setConstraints(this.portLabel, c);

        //port input
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.fill = 1;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 7;
        gbl.setConstraints(this.portField, c);

        //change port button
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.fill = 1;
        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 7;
        gbl.setConstraints(this.changePort, c);

        //connect button
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.fill = 1;
        c.gridx = 4;
        c.gridy = 7;
        gbl.setConstraints(this.connectButton, c);

        //disconnect button, shunned in the corner
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.fill = 1;
        c.gridx = 4;
        c.gridy = 8;
        gbl.setConstraints(this.disconnectButton, c);

        mb.add(colorMenu);
        colorMenu.add(redItem);
        colorMenu.add(blueItem);
        colorMenu.add(orangeItem);
        colorMenu.add(blackItem);


        add(this.conversationBox);
        add(this.inputBox);
        add(this.sendButton);
        add(this.hostLabel);
        add(this.hostField);
        add(this.changeHost);
        add(this.startServerButton);
        add(this.portLabel);
        add(this.portField);
        add(this.changePort);
        add(this.connectButton);
        add(this.disconnectButton);

        inputBox.addActionListener(this);
        sendButton.addActionListener(this);
        changeHost.addActionListener(this);
        changePort.addActionListener(this);
        startServerButton.addActionListener(this);
        connectButton.addActionListener(this);
        disconnectButton.addActionListener(this);
        hostField.addActionListener(this);
        portField.addActionListener(this);
        redItem.addItemListener(this);
        blueItem.addItemListener(this);
        orangeItem.addItemListener(this);
        blackItem.addItemListener(this);

        setMenuBar(mb);
        addWindowListener(this);
        setResizable(true);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);

        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void run()
    {   
        conversationBox.appendText("Session Start.\n");
        inputBox.requestFocus();

        while (!kill)
        {
            if (isServer)
            {
                conversationBox.appendText("Server starting on port " + port + "\n");
                conversationBox.appendText("Waiting for clients...\n");
                startServer();
            }
            if (isClient)
            {
                conversationBox.appendText("Starting connection to host " + host + " on port " + port + "\n");
                startClient();
            }
        }       

    }

    public void startClient()
    {
        try
        {
            Socket c = new Socket(host, port);
            in = new Scanner(c.getInputStream());
            out = new PrintWriter(c.getOutputStream());
            while (true)
            {
                if (in.hasNext())
                {
                    Chat.conversationBox.appendText("You Said: " + message);
                    out.println("Client Said: " + message);
                    out.flush();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void startServer()
    {
        try
        {
            server = new ServerSocket(port);
            while (true)
            {
                s = server.accept();
                conversationBox.appendText("Client connected from " + s.getLocalAddress().getHostName() + "\n");    
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            conversationBox.appendText("An error occurred.\n");
            e.printStackTrace();
            isServer = false;
            reEnableAll();
        }

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) throws NumberFormatException
    {
        Object o = e.getSource();

        if (o == sendButton || o == inputBox)
        {
            if(inputBox.getText() != "")
            {
                out.println(inputBox.getText());
                inputBox.setText("");
            }
        }
        if (o == changeHost || o == hostField)
        {
            if (hostField.getText() != "" && hostField.getText() != host)
            {
                host = hostField.getText();
                conversationBox.appendText("Host changed to " + host + "\n");
            }
        }
        if (o == changePort || o == portField)
        {
            if (portField.getText() != "" && Integer.valueOf(portField.getText()) != port)
            {
                try
                {
                    port = Integer.valueOf(portField.getText());
                    conversationBox.appendText("Port changed to " + port + "\n");
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException up)
                {
                    throw up; //blargh enter a real value
                }
            }
        }
        if (o == startServerButton)
        {
            isServer = true;
            isClient = false;
            startServerButton.enable(false);
            connectButton.enable(false);
            changeHost.enable(false);
            changePort.enable(false);
            hostField.enable(false);
            portField.enable(false);
        }
        if (o == connectButton)
        {
            isServer = false;
            isClient = true;
            startServerButton.enable(false);
        }
        inputBox.requestFocus();
    }

    public void reEnableAll()
    {
        startServerButton.enable(true);
        connectButton.enable(true);
        changeHost.enable(true);
        changePort.enable(true);
        hostField.enable(true);
        portField.enable(true);
    }

    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
    {
        removeWindowListener(this);
        inputBox.removeActionListener(this);
        sendButton.removeActionListener(this);
        changeHost.removeActionListener(this);
        changePort.removeActionListener(this);
        startServerButton.removeActionListener(this);
        connectButton.removeActionListener(this);
        disconnectButton.removeActionListener(this);
        dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e){}
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e){}
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e){}
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e){}
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e){}
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e){}

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
    {
        Object o = e.getSource();
        if (o == redItem)
        {
            redItem.setState(true);
            blueItem.setState(false);
            orangeItem.setState(false);
            blackItem.setState(false);
            color = Color.red;
        }

        if (o == blueItem)
        {
            redItem.setState(false);
            blueItem.setState(true);
            orangeItem.setState(false);
            blackItem.setState(false);
            color = Color.red;          
        }

        if (o == orangeItem)
        {
            redItem.setState(false);
            blueItem.setState(false);
            orangeItem.setState(true);
            blackItem.setState(false);
            color = Color.red;          
        }

        if (o == blackItem)
        {
            redItem.setState(false);
            blueItem.setState(false);
            orangeItem.setState(false);
            blackItem.setState(true);
            color = Color.red;          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to start a thread for each client

Comment: Okay, sounds about right.  how do I go about doing that, though?  Just a `Thread t = new Thread(this)` inside of startClient?  And after that's done, how do I go about sending the value of the textField to the server (and back from the server to the clients)?  thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I test your code, I find that in your startServer() function, you don't create an OutputStream and InputStream

Modify your `startClient` function like this: (create two global variables : `BufferedWriter bw` and `BufferedReader br`, because we need it in your `actionPerformed` function)

```
BufferedWriter bw = null;
BufferedReader br = null;
public void startClient()
{
    try
    {
        Socket c = new Socket(host, port);

        bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(c.getOutputStream()));
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));

        char buffer[] = new char[1024];
        while (br.read(buffer) > 0)
        {
            Chat.conversationBox.appendText("You Said: " + new String(buffer));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Modify your `startServer` function like this :

```
public void startServer()
{
    try
    {
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
        while (true)
        {

            s = server.accept();

            s.getInputStream();

            conversationBox.appendText("Client connected from " + s.getLocalAddress().getHostName() + "\n");

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));

            char buffer[] = new char[1024];
            conversationBox.appendText("Reading....");
            while(br.read(buffer) > 0)
            {
                conversationBox.appendText("Client Say : " + new String(buffer));
                bw.write(buffer);
                bw.flush();
            }
            conversationBox.appendText("Reading Done....");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        conversationBox.appendText("An error occurred.\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
        isServer = false;
        reEnableAll();
    }
}
```

And in your `actionPerformed` function, please modify following codes:

```
    if (o == sendButton || o == inputBox)
    {
        if (inputBox == null)
        {
            System.out.println("NULL");
        }

        if(inputBox.getText() != "")
        {
            //out.println(inputBox.getText());
            //out.flush();

            try
            {
                bw.write(inputBox.getText());
                bw.flush();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            inputBox.setText("");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Alright, doing that now.  <br> Okay, so, that's done.  And I understand that that created an OutputStream, but I still don't quite understand how i interface to that with the textField.  Sorry if my questions are dumb

Comment: okay, so, I went in and added those two lines, but they didn't do anything.  Also, in our actionPerformed, we have the value of the textfield going into PrintWriter out, so if I just have s.getOutputStream(), the server gives an error when I type because it has nothing to put into out.  I still don't know what do to after I create the output stream and inputstream

Comment: @Alex Kibler I edited the answer.. By the way, I suggest using multi-thread to handle client-server communication.

Comment: I've tested it, it works.. but it can only handle single client.. but at least it gives ideas to create multi-thread to solve chatting problem

Comment: wow, thank you!  I'm going to implement this right now.  I know beggars can't be choosers, but do you know what it would take to implement multiple clients?

Comment: I think you need to create a new Class, which implement `Runnable` interface, this new CLass is used to encapsulate accepted client, then just put `reading` and `writing` function in `run` .

Comment: In `while (true)` loop within `startServer` funcion, you just need to wait for client, each time you accept a new client, just create this new Class and start this new Class, then go to wait for the next one.

Comment: Alright, well, that definitely sounds do-able.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome.. I also met many problems when I tried to write my chatting program before..

Comment: Oh, one more question, @bhuang3, how do i disconnect from the sockets?  I know that I use server.close() to close the sockets, but when i put them in the disconnect button's actionPerformed, it says there's a potential IOException, and I can't make actionPerformed throw IOException.

Comment: Oh, and, how can I make it so that server can type as well?  When I try to type as server, I get a NullPointerException at bw.write(inputBox.getText());

Comment: Before I close a socket connection, I will send a `Closing Message` to server. when server receive this message, it will close input and ouput stream, then close or interrupt thread.

Comment: I think you need to reconstruct your code... I don't recommend to put all operation codes in one single function..

Comment: how do you mean I need to reconstruct it?  I definitely understand using multiple functions, and I can do that if i need to, but what do you think needs to be moved outside of the function?

Comment: Because the `BufferedWriter bw` you use in `actionPerformed` is created in `startClient` function, when you start as server, you invoke `startServer` rather than `startClient` function

Comment: Okay, one more question: How do I kill the server?  I made a function called "closeSockets" that just has s.close and server.close, and inside of the while(br.read(buffer) > 0) loop in startServer, I made an if statement check the value of a boolean that is set by the disconnectButton.  However, this doesn't work.  Any clue why?

Comment: Okay, sounds good.  i've never done anything with interrupts though.  I know i can use thread.interrupt() to interrupt a thread, but the thread was created as new Thread(this).start(); so I don't know what the thread is called or how to interrupt it